# An adder that receives 2 lifetimed structs, can't add

Tags: rust

I reduced my code to this minimum verifiable example:

```rust
use core::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait Engine<P> {
    fn add_assign(
        &self,
        left: &mut P,
        right: &P,
    ) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

pub struct A<'a, R> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a R>
}

pub fn add_both(a1: &mut A<'_, u64>,
                a2: &A<'_, u64>,
                engine: &dyn Engine<A<'_, u64>>) 
{
    engine.add_assign(a1,a2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b7197e2b1412cef7b9942b3edfc02a45)

which won't compile due to lifetime problems. One solution would be to have the same lifetime on all arguments, but I don't want that for other reasons. Also I really need `engine` to be a `dyn` object.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong bug Every occurrence of `P` has same implicit lifetime, this means that in order to make lifetimes distinct, you need more parameters.

```rust
use core::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait EngineParam {
    type Param<'a>;
}

pub trait Engine<A, B> {
    fn add_assign(&self, left: &mut A, right: &B) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

pub struct A<'a, R> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a R>,
}

pub fn add_both<'a, 'b>(
    a1: &mut A<'a, u64>,
    a2: &A<'b, u64>,
    engine: &dyn Engine<A<'a, u64>, A<'b, u64>>,
) {
    engine.add_assign(a1, a2);
}
```